# Is there a way to discuss a triage review with the reviewer?

Tags: discussion, triage

During my reviews in the triage queue, I sometimes notice some really strange reviews by some of the users.
For example, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21875689) question (the question is currently deleted).

First, this question is obviously a homework question. 
There is no sign that the OP tried solving the problem by himself. He didn't explain what he is stuck at or what he tried so far.

He just pasted some code and laid out the issue for us to solve.

So by looking at the question, I decided that I should mark it as "Unsalvageable" or more specifically, "Too Broad".

After some time, I checked the reviews on the question and I was really surprised when I saw that there were 2 "Looks OK" reviews. I thought that maybe OP updated the question but that was not the case.

I checked the profiles of the users and it looks to me like that these were not their first reviews (they even have more rep than me).

So I am curious, is there a way for me to contact them and ask them what made them mark that question as "Looks OK"?
What should I do in situations like these?

Comment: Will that be an "What on earth made you think that looked OK"  or an "I want to improve my reviewing and like to compare your and my reviews" type of question?

Comment: Well I would genuinely like to ask them what made them vote that way. Maybe there is something that I am missing. On the other hand, I might prove them wrong and they will be able to improve their reviews.

Comment: You could try [SOCVR chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if you want a second opinion on how you reviewed a specific task when it is completed. Ask something along the line of: "I'm wondering if I have reviewed this correctly and if not, what I should learn from this". Do go over our tour and FAQ found [here](https://socvr.org/).

Comment: @rene thanks for the info, I will check that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really only one way to accomplish that, which would be to invite them to chat. Please avoid leaving a comment on one of their posts or directly calling them out on Meta.

In general though, for concerns regarding reviews, the broader meta audience will often be able to offer a large range of advice for what happened during a review.

Moreover, bringing specific situations to Meta for analysis while leaving out individual issues is more helpful, as it allows generic behaviors or circumstances to be observed and discussed. Maybe more users are also confused or concerned about handling the same type of review.

---

This specific question should have been rather clear though for the review queue. Too broad was definitely accurate, or even unclear or lacking a clear problem statement. I don't see how that question looked okay. I am not sure anyone else would really disagree, so the above advice would probably just be one large echo chamber of "close it".

Comment: This might have been a case where "requires editing" was maybe an acceptable review, as the 1st revision had some code layout issues. At least it was not as wrong as it often is.

Comment: @rene - Perhaps with a great edit from the OP, the question could be have become legitimate. So I agree there. However, that is the case with so many questions which are asked here.

Comment: @rene "Requires editing" is for posts that are on topic posts that don't merit closure, but that could just use a bit of work to be better.  Not for posts with major problems, that merit closure, but that *also* have some formatting problems.  No matter how unsalvageable a post is, there's probably some grammar/formatting edit that you could make.  That doesn't mean the post should be marked as "requires editing".

Comment: @servy I tried to suggest that I see light at the end of the triage tunnel while you still assume it is a train we see that is speeding towards us. It is a fair position, I was in an optimistic mood. It has been corrected now.