# Why is this broad question considered OK?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, triage

I was reviewing some questions in the triage queue, and I came upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/22709847). I decided that it is too broad, because the OP did not post any code and it looks like that he is looking for a tutorial.

If someone would like to really answer this question, he/she will have to write a lot of backend and frontend code. In short, there is no specific problem that the OP encountered; he is asking how to implement a certain feature.

Anyway, I see that my "too broad" flag was disputed and three other people voted that this question is "OK". So, are there any other interpretations of the question or am I wrong to assume that questions of this type should be flagged as "too broad"?

Comment: *"Why is this question considered OK?"* - IMO, it's not and have voted to close as too broad

Comment: Yes,  it is not considered a good question, but now Meta will close it anyway!

Comment: Yeah this question is far too broad as straight away it's asking two questions in one. It seems like the question they _actually_ want to ask is "How to reduce api calls to update the user information on the client" which imo even that is pushing  off-topic

Comment: I just cast the fifth VtC as too broad which closed it. (Personally I find the error rate on most types of flags on most SE sites unacceptably high and I don't have the time to post on Meta every time flags are wrongly handled.)

Comment: @smci I agree with your findings, in addition it appears OP has [run into this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378741/is-there-a-way-to-discuss-a-triage-review-with-the-reviewer), which shows how common it is considering they haven't had review tools that long to be able to see it

Comment: I am sorry that the question title is considered too broad but I couldn't think of a better title. I am not sure if I should post questions like this on meta but I feel that if questions like this are left as "OK" people will keep making the same mistake.

Comment: @DimitarSpasovski Not your question, the question you linked to :), your question is fine

Comment: Maybe it's okay to ask these questions on meta to get a second opinion, but then again, this particular problem is solved, and I do wonder what use this question has for the archive. Is there some clean-up of obsolete [specific-question] questions, or should there be?

Comment: A quick look at the 3 "OK" reviewers reveals that we have 1600, 600 and 1200 rep. I've found people with lower reputation tend to be overly generous with their reviews (largely from lack of experience)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you were right to flag it as Too Broad. For what it's worth, the question is now closed and deleted.

Keep in mind that sometimes reviewers get it wrong, and sometimes there are folks reviewing without paying close enough attention (or reviewing in tags they don't have knowledge of).

If you ever find yourself in this situation, the appropriate thing is what you did here: ask on Meta. That way, Meta will either rectify the issue or provide education on why the question is actually OK.